# Are there any services or post services that can help me change email encoding and forward ir?

Tags: email, microservices, html-email

Here is the situation:
There is a website with a form that send email to my gmail account.
After that, i want to redirect it to crm called ammocrm.
The problem is that the original email has encoding `charset=iso-8859-1` and ammocrm does not support it. And the main thing - i cant make any changes in website code.
Do you know any tricks that can help me handle it? Like services or post services that can retrive email, change its encoding and send id next? I am realy doest want to make microservice that doese it.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Which encodings does receiving soft support?  Does the mail are plain text only? [No attachments to alternative html]

Comment: It definetly supports html with utf-8

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like Zapier that can link up emails into CRMs, https://zapier.com/apps/amocrm/integrations. Also, check for Zapier alternatives.